# SQL: Query a Table that only has All Matching Values

Tags: sql

I have a table of attributes (Name / Value Pair) for a specific product. I am trying to query against this table to give me all products that match a series of attributes.

Example :

```
ProductId |  AttributeName | AttributeValue 
1         |  Color         | Blue 
1         |  Size          | Large
1         |  Manufacturer  |  Things R' Us  
2         |  Color         | Blue
2         |  Size          | Small
```

I want a query that I can run against this table to give me a list of products that have a color of BLUE and a size of Large.

If I do a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ProductId] 
FROM [dbo].[Product_Attributes] 
WHERE ( AttributeName = 'Color' AND AttributeValue = 'Blue')  
  AND ( AttributeName = 'Size' AND AttributeValue = 'Large' )
```

I get nothing back because nothing matches all of those criteria.

If I do an "OR" based query - then I will get Products that may only match *one* of the attributes that I am querying for.

***I would want a query that returns only ProductId 1, because that is the only item that has both a color of blue and a size of large***

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Please add the expected result to your question ([Edit])

Comment: The answer to this question will help you. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527780/how-to-query-and-obtain-a-result-set-containing-at-minimum-the-set-of-values-sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to solve it is via aggregation:

```
SELECT [ProductId] 
FROM [dbo].[Product_Attributes] 
WHERE ( AttributeName = 'Color' AND AttributeValue = 'Blue')  
  OR ( AttributeName = 'Size' AND AttributeValue = 'Large' )
GROUP by [ProductId] 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30e3ef/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try a subset query like:

```
SELECT * from 
[dbo].[Product_Attributes]  WHERE [ProductId]
IN
( SELECT DISTINCT [ProductId] 
FROM [dbo].[Product_Attributes] 
WHERE ( AttributeName = 'Color' AND AttributeValue = 'Blue')  
)
AND
AttributeName = 'Size' AND AttributeValue = 'Large'
```

Comment: The difficulty with this answer is that this is obviously a sample table. The actual table contains many thousands of rows with many thousands of arbitrary name / value combinations. 

The query will be build dynamically, so the search function may be trying to match on many different things at once.

Answer (score 1):

[Check This](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7afap9azv8SPBGx9DdUZLu/0)

```
select t1.productId from Table1 t1
inner join Table1 t2
  on t2.AttributeName = 'Size'  and 
     t2.AttributeValue = 'Large' and 
     t1.productId = t2.productId
where t1.AttributeName = 'Color'  and t1.AttributeValue = 'Blue'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY [ProductId]` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT [ProductId] 
FROM [dbo].[Product_Attributes] 
GROUP BY [ProductId]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeName = 'Color' AND AttributeValue = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) > 0  
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN AttributeName = 'Size' AND AttributeValue = 'Large' THEN 1 END) > 0
```